# Erasing an element from the vector during iteration c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I wrote this method to find the minor of a sparse matrix:

```
SpMatrixVec SparseMatrix::minor(SpMatrixVec matrix, int col) const{

    SpMatrixVec::iterator it = matrix.begin();

    int currRow = it->getRow();

    int currCol = col;

    while(it != matrix.end()) {

        if(it->getRow() == currRow || it->getCol() == currCol){
            matrix.erase(it);
        }
        // if we have deleted an element in the array, it doesn't advance the
        // iterator and size() will be decreased by one.
        else{   
            it++;
        }

    }

    // now, we alter the cells of the minor matrix to be of proper coordinates.
    // this is necessary for sign computation (+/-) in the determinant recursive
    // formula of detHelper(), since the minor matrix non-zero elements are now
    // in different coordinates. The row is always decreased by one, since we
    // work witht he first line, and the col is decreased by one if the element
    // was located after 'col' (which this function receives as a parameter).

    //change the cells of the minor to their proper coordinates.
    for(it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); it++){

        it->setRow(it->getRow()-1);

        int newY;
        newY = (it->getCol() > col) ? it->getCol() + 1 : it->getCol();

        it->setCol(newY);
    }
    return matrix;

}
```

Now, i'm probably doing something wrong, because when reaching the second interation of the `while` loop, the program crashes.
The basic idea was to go over the vector, and see if it is the relevant coordinate, and if so - to delete it. I increment the iterator only if there was no deletion (and in this case, the vector should update the iterator to be pointing the next element..unless i got these things wrong).

Where is the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are SpMatrixVec and SparseMatrix defined?

Comment: it++ :( ++it :) of course this is not the problem, but the problem has been already properly addressed

Comment: If this is a vector, you'll be much better off using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom because that would copy things around just once, whereas each individual erasure in your code would have to copy down all the following elements.

Answer (score 9):

`erase()` invalidates your iterator.

You must update `it` using the return value of `erase()` for the loop to work:

```
while(it != matrix.end()) {

    if(it->getRow() == currRow || it->getCol() == currCol){
        //matrix.erase(it);
        it = matrix.erase(it); // Here is the change
    }
    // if we have deleted an element in the array, it doesn't advance the
    // iterator and size() will be decreased by one.
    else{   
        //it++;
        ++it; // ++i is usually faster than i++. It's a good habit to use it.
    }

}
```

Comment: @Steve Townsend: Absolutely, I wasn't checking for any other "error" in the code but you're indeed absolutely right. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: This code is a little dangerous, you have to detect if the iterator points to the last element in the vector and handle that specifically.  I learned this the hard way by using this example ;-)

Comment: @Benj: I don't follow. What could be dangerous when reaching the last element ? If you erase `it` and the new `it` becomes `matrix.end()` then the looping condition is unsatisfied and control exits the loop.

Answer (score 6):

`erase` invalidates your iterator. Do `it = matrix.erase(it)` instead.

Answer (score -2):

You can't change a collection while you're iterating between its elements.
Use another temp collection to store the partial results.

edit: Even better, use a functor to delete elements: `remove_if`
You write the condition.

Comment: That's just plain wrong. You may modify it while iterating, you just have to ensure that the iterators aren't invalidated while you do it.

Comment: No, it is possible to do it. You just have to store the return value of `erase` to get a new, valid iterator.